# What is the difference between "Skip" and "Leave Open" in the Close Vote queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

What is the effective difference between *Skip* and *Leave open*? Leaving the question open does not seem to remove the close votes, so how does it actually work?

Comment: I can't remember precisely but enough leave opens remove it from the review queue

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Skip" is a no-vote, or you abstaining from voting. Your "Skip" has no effect on the question being closed, or left open.

"Leave Open" is you voting *against* the question being closed. If enough (3) people vote for "Leave Open", the post is removed from the Close Vote queue, and the [aging process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/220651) starts immediately. For more information, see [What exactly happens with the button “Leave Open” (previously “Do Not Close”)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/163863)

---

**Skip** if you're not sure whether the post should be closed or not. **Leave Open** if you're sure the post shouldn't be closed.